# save basic information in a cookie or get in mysql all the time?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have some information like the user full name and the profile picture that I need to access this information all the time in mysql. (all pages that he visits)

I was thinking to get this information once when user login and store this in a COOKIE. So every page I get this information in this cookie to avoid mysql connection for this everytime. (if the cookie is not set or lost date, I check mysql).

is it a good solution or a no sense one? can I have problems doing this? anyone has tried some similar thing?

thank you friends!

*EDIT:
I don't want to store LOGIN information in a cookie, I have SESSION for this. Just want to set a cookie for irrelevant information, his profile picture, his full name... not login access data.*

Comment: Sessions > Cookies for personally identifiable information like this.

Comment: @Darren I save session in mysql, so in the end, I need to check mysql to get it...  but yeah, I need to get session anyway so I can store this there. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing information in cookie to remember login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384776/storing-information-in-cookie-to-remember-login)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384776/storing-information-in-cookie-to-remember-login?rq=1

Comment: @RahulDambare I just want to store his name and his profile picture... not his access data.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Darren suggested, you should never use cookies for personal information - those are rather easy to be recovered from public computers. Besides, there's no real drawback of loading the MySQL every time, unless you're *very* tight on bandwidth. 
My suggestion would to use a script like this:

```
$sql = new mysql("localhost", "Some_user", "some_password", "some_db");
$handle = $sql -> query("SELECT * FROM users_or_something");
while ($row = $handle -> fetch_object()){
   $name = $row -> name;
   $img_url = $row -> img;
   //...

}
```

And then...

```
include "db_load.php";
```

in every page.

Or even better, include it in your login processing page, then use $_SESSION[] to pass it between your scripts.

For faster logins, you could however store some user ID as a cookie and then, if the user opts in for auto-login, look for it. In that case, make the login page (index.php)? look for it before displaying a login form.

From a purely technical point of view, you can store pretty much anything as a cookie, if you can retrieve it. There's nothing (technically) wrong with what you're suggesting.

Comment: thank you for your answer friends! In fact I have both, session and cookies. Session is for the username and user_id to access my website login. BUT I would create a cookie for some irrelevant information, such as his full name and profile picture. I don't want to store his login information in a cookie!

Comment: @Rick Joe: That will work. As I said, there's nothing wrong with it. I just doubt that would be much an improvement, since you're basically loading the same thing from another place. Do what you're more comfortable with. My personal choice is MySQL.